# Where to instantiate the ViewPager - resource not found exception

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I'm following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zQekzaAgIlQ) instruction video from the google android developers channel to create a simple app with tabs.

Unfortunately when putting the code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.content_pager);
PagerAdapter pagerAdapter = new ContentPager(getSupportFragmentManager());
viewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);

TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.content_tabs);
tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

...
```

into my MainActivitys onCreate I get the exception message:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.smilingkoala.ping/com.smilingkoala.ping.MainActivity}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x7f080050
```

Are the requested resources not available yet, and I simply need to Instantiate the ViewPager somewhere else, or did I make some fundamental mistake?

Edit - found the solution after @Chol s comment. Below the old code:
The cunstructor of ContetnPager looked as follows

```
public ContentPager(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }
```

with the getPageTitle method:

```
@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            return Resource.getSystem().getString(R.string.pings_page_title);
        case 1:
            return Resources.getSystem().getString(R.string.contacts_page_title);
        default:
            return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Put the line of the code where it crash here.

Comment: Can you share ContentPager.class ??

Comment: Most of the time this issue is due when setting an integer to a textview.setText(). Take a look to your getTitle() method in the ContentPager

Comment: @Chol you where right. I'll update the question and post my solution. It would be nice if you could take a look at it. I wouldn't want to spread bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

My solution (thanks to @Chol s comment)

Change the ContentPager constructor to:

```
public ContentPager(FragmentManager fm, Context m_context) {
    super(fm);
    context = m_context;
}
```

and the getPageTitle method to:

```
@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            return context.getResources().getString(R.string.pings_page_title);
        case 1:
            return context.getResources().getString(R.string.contacts_page_title);
        default:
            return null;
    }
}
```

changed code in onCreate to:

```
    ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.content_pager);
    PagerAdapter pagerAdapter = new ContentPager(getSupportFragmentManager(), this);
    viewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);

    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.content_tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
```

Comment: yeah that's how it has to be done, passing context threw adapter constructor to get the ressources

Answer (score 0):

Just update like this:

```
@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            return String.valueOf(context.getResources().getString(R.string.pings_page_title));
        case 1:
            return String.valueOf(context.getResources().getString(R.string.contacts_page_title));
        default:
            return "";
    }
}
```